# Geometry nodes: create array like object with rotations

Tags: geometry-nodes

a. I'm new to Geometry Nodes and would like to ask how can one achieve the following using them:

1. take an object (could be the monkey head) as reference
2. place one more such object just above (on z-axis) the first one and rotate it 90 degrees
3. add third one above the second and rotate 90 degrees more. And so on...

b. Does it create a real mesh, or only the first reference object is "real"? (i.e. can I, e.g., connect some vertices from the first bottom object with the vertices of the last into a single mesh?)

Comment: For Blender 4.0 experimental build try [Repeat Zone](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/geometry_nodes/utilities/repeat_zone.html) ... [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NbCJjnqJovY) is some explanation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use simplified [quellenform's answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/265999/145249) ... this node tree is assigned to Monkey.
*Mesh Line > Count* use for number of instances. *Empty* object is used for *Loc, Rot* offset step ...

[image]
[image]

**Blender 4.+** ... you can test [Repeat Zone](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/geometry_nodes/utilities/repeat_zone.html) for even more simpler way ...

[image]

Comment: what about question (b)?

Comment: It depends :) You can add Realise Instances node, than you can access any vertex in generated mesh. The problematic part would be to create a selection of these specific vertices. It really depends what do you want to connect. Or if you don't mind you can Apply modifier and connect then manually in edit mode.