# How can I rotate a mesh line?

Tags: mesh, geometry-nodes

I have a mesh line and I duplicate it to create 5 more lines. However, I want each line to be rotated 45 degrees. The problem is the red line, I am not able to dynamically add input to the node *Transform*.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Probably duplicate? https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/297889/2214

Comment: Added image to clarify my issue. The issue is that I am not able to dynamically add input to the Transform Geometry node based on the index of the Duplicate Element. Please advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The node `Transform` does not work with fields, but with single values. This issue is described here:
[Why is there a red line when I try to connect one node to another?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274557/why-is-there-a-red-line-when-i-try-to-connect-one-node-to-another/274558#274558)

In your use case, however, you have fields and would have to use the node `Set Position`.

This processes your geometry point by point, so you would have to calculate the individual positions of the points.

Since you want to rotate points around a certain center, the node `Vector Rotate` will help you.

And a solution could look like this:

[image]

Comment: Can combine xyz be input to transform geometry and used here instead of set position?

Comment: nvm, the output of duplicate elements is attribute domain and can only be operated/transformed via set position

Comment: @ph_zero Absolutely correct: You are dealing with *Fields* here, so `Transform Geometry` does not work in this case, and you would have to use `Set Position` instead.